# Indy somethimes throws EIdOSSLCreatingContextError

Tags: multithreading, delphi, indy

I have a scheduled task that runs every 15 mins.
The scheduled task starts a multi threaded service that sends web requests to a web server. Sometimes, but not always, the `TidHTTP.Post` throws a `EIdOSSLCreatingContextError` exception. It's practically impossible for me to reproduce in a debug environment, but my log has 344 instances of the exception over the course of 10 days.
Here is the code that crashes, be aware that multiple threads can reach this code at the same time:

```
class function THTTPClient.Post(aUrl : string; aPayload : string; 
aHeaderFields : TStringList) : string;
var
  oHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  ssPayload: TStringStream;
  bSecure: Boolean;
  sslIOHandler:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  oHTTP := nil;
  ssPayload := TStringStream.Create(aPayload, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    oHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    oHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddStrings(aHeaderFields);
    bSecure := StartsText('HTTPS:', aUrl);
    if bSecure then
    begin
      sslIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(oHTTP);
      sslIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
      sslIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
      sslIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      sslIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      sslIOHandler.Host := '';
      sslIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3];

      oHTTP.IOHandler := sslIOHandler;
    end;
    oHTTP.HandleRedirects := true;

    try
      Result := oHTTP.Post(aUrl, ssPayload);
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        Result := E.Message;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    oHTTP.Free;
    ssPayload.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Eurekalog is used to log the errors. Here is the exception details:

```
Application:
--------------------------------------------------------------
1.1 Start Date      : Tue, 5 Jun 2018 03:52:26 +0200
1.2 Name/Description: AutoRunMT.exe
1.3 Version Number  : 7.12.48.94
1.4 Parameters      : 
1.5 Compilation Date: Fri, 18 May 2018 10:45:35 +0200
1.6 Up Time         : 23 hour(s), 21 minute(s), 59 second(s)

Exception:
----------------------------------------------------
2.1 Date          : Wed, 6 Jun 2018 03:14:25 +0200
2.2 Address       : 006625DF
2.3 Module Name   : AutoRunMT.exe
2.4 Module Version: 7.12.48.94
2.5 Type          : EIdOSSLCreatingContextError
2.6 Message       : Error creating SSL context.
2.7 ID            : E99A7A81
2.8 Count         : 1
2.9 Status        : New
2.10 Note         : 
2.11 Sent         : 0
```

Comment: On a side note, not related to your error, `SSLOptions.Method` and `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` are mutually exclusive, you should be setting one or the other, not both.

Comment: `EIdOSSLCreatingContextError` is raised when OpenSSL's `SSL_CTX_new()` fails. What is the complete message message of the exception? It also has an `ErrorCode` property, what is its value?

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Ah okay, thanks! I'm not sure which error code you are referring to. I cannot reproduce this error when debugging, but I will attach the exception details in the question.

Comment: I'm referring to the `EIdOSSLCreatingContextError.ErrorCode` property.